# Inner border that sits on top of content of the whole page

Tags: css

I need to create a layout that has an inner border around the whole page that sits on top of the content like below.

[image]

So far I have

```
body::before {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 22px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

But that only extends to the height of the window, it doesn't extend to cover the whole of the page's content.

Some of the different sections of the page need to extend to the full width of the window so I can't wrap the whole page in a `div` and apply border styles to that, the element with the border needs to sit on top of everything else.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: the code you have provided completely doesn't explain your problem, try to make a small demo of what is the problem with the content which is extending as well ? that will help you get better answers

Comment: fixed instead of absolute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way I have found is to create an element that sits over the others on your site:

```
    <div class="overlay">
       <div class="overlay-border"></div>
    </div>
```

And then add the appropriate styling:

```
.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 99;
}
.overlay-border{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #111;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The "z-index: 99" might need to be increased if you start allocating z-index to other elements. "pointer-events: none" ensures that website users can still click on links and other elements behind the overlay.

You can also change "position: absolute" to "position: fixed" if you would like this overlay across the whole window.

And then if you want the overlay across the entire page you can add this simple javascript:

```
    var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;
    var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
    html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
    document.querySelector('.overlay').style.height = height + 'px';
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this, however, this was just in the interim as I found my solution and I look forward to seeing the easier ways to do this :)

Comment: This seems to work well except for some reason the value of `height` in the js is about 50px too short.

Comment: you can do:  document.querySelector('.overlay').style.height = height + 50 + 'px';
and just adjust the 50 until it sits right

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Just wondered why it wouldn't give the correct value though.

Comment: Calculating window height on browsers can be a bit tricky as it may be accommodating for a horizontal scrollbar if you may need it hence the extra space at the bottom... that is my best guess. On my side the window height was perfect and sat at an even distance on all sides. It may also be browser related. You can also try * { box-sizing: border-box }

Comment: I think the problem was I hadn't wrapped the script in a window on load event so it was calculating the height too early.

Comment: very well could have been too, glad it is sorted :)